# Cannot find sn.exe to sign Assembly

Tags: c#, msbuild, sn.exe

I looked into `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET` and I can't see any `SN.exe` file.

I have .NET 3.5 runtime installed; isn't that enough ?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio command prompt it should work out of the box

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to install the Windows SDK 6.0a, not just the runtime.

If you've installed VS2008, you'll find it's already installed, and sn.exe will be here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\sn.exe

Otherwise, if you don't have VS2008 installed, you can download the SDK individually [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en).

The file sn.exe is not available in the SDK.  The current version of the SDK is 6.1, perhaps they removed sn.exe in this release.

Comment: What about the 64 bit version?

Comment: For me on a Windows 7 64-bit using VS2010, the path to sn.exe was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sn.exe`

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 24):

- open command prompt
- type `cd \`
- type `dir /s sn.exe`
- you will get output something like

  `Volume in drive C has no label.`

  `Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX.`

Directory of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin`

```
11/07/2007  12:01 PM            95,728 sn.exe
              1 File(s)         95,728 bytes
```

You found the directory :)
if not, there is no `sn.exe` in your system. Install SDK then.

Answer (score 5):

*I'm sure you have your reasons -- and there are definitely plenty cases where `SN.exe` is unavoidable and/or appropriate (Delay Signing for one). **(And I've +1'd the Q and the Accepted A and am not disputing their merit in any way so please disregard this if it doesn't apply in your case)***

Note that `SN.exe` is rarely needed in practice - the wiring in `Microft.<lang>.targets` that drive the compilers [and `AL.exe` etc.] all [effectively] take the `SignAssembly` flag in the .proj file into account and conditionally pass in the key to the compiler(s) etc. so it can do all the work in a single touch of the assembly inline (mainly for perf reasons).

This logic also deals with the distinction between `.snk` and `.pfx` keys (which are password protected and get secreted into a Key Container). Depending on which form, there is then either a `KeyContainerName` or `KeyOriginatorFile` property resolved by `Microsoft.Common.targets` in the Runtime directory - Search for `ResolveKeySource`.

If the reason you need to do a `SN` is because you've just rewritten an assembly, the same pattern should generally hold, i.e. `Mono.Cecil` and tools a la PostSharp (I assume, not confirmed) generally also take the same arguments and/or can be made to do the signing inline.

---

#### Microsoft.Common.targets excerpt

```
<Target Name="ResolveKeySource" 
  Condition="$(SignManifests) == 'true' or $(SignAssembly) == 'true'">

  <ResolveKeySource ...
    KeyFile="$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)"
    CertificateFile="$(ManifestKeyFile)"
    SuppressAutoClosePasswordPrompt="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ResolvedKeyFile" PropertyName="KeyOriginatorFile" ..."/>
      <Output TaskParameter="ResolvedKeyContainer" PropertyName="KeyContainerName" ... "/>
```

#### Microsoft.CSharp.targets excerpt

```
    <Csc  ...
          KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)"
          KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)" />
```

---

For completeness, here's how to programmatically infer the SDK path relevant to the target you are compiling (tested on 4.0 but same approach is possible all the way back to 2.0, i.e. `Microsoft.Common.targets` has processed this data for some time):

```
<Target Name="ResolveSNToolPath" Condition=" 'true' == '$(SignAssembly)' ">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_SdkToolsBinDir Condition=" '' == '$(_SdkToolsBinDir)' ">$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)</_SdkToolsBinDir>
      <SNToolPath Condition=" '' == '$(SNToolPath)' ">$(_SdkToolsBinDir)SN.exe</SNToolPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition=" 'true' == '$(SignAssembly)' AND !EXISTS( '$(SNToolPath)' )"
      Text="In order to resign the assembly, this package requires access to the SN.EXE tool from the Windows Platform SDK, which was not found.

The location derived was &quot;$(SNToolPath)&quot;.

Please either:
1) supply a correct path to your SDK Tools bin directory containing SN.EXE by setting %24(_SdkToolsBinDir) or %24(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)
OR
2) supply a correct complete path to your SN.EXE signing tool by setting %24(SNToolPath)" />
  </Target>
```

---

For total completeness, here's how you would leverage the outputs of this process to run SN.exe

```
<Target Name="ResignMyAssembly" Condition="$(SignAssembly) == 'true'">
  <Exec Condition=" '$(KeyContainerName)' != '' " 
    Command="&quot;$(SNToolPath)&quot; -Rca &quot;@(MyAssembly)&quot; &quot;$(KeyContainerName)&quot; " />
  <Exec Condition=" '$(KeyContainerName)' == '' " 
    Command="&quot;$(SlpsSdkProtectSnTool)&quot; -Ra &quot;@(MyAssembly)&quot; &quot;$(KeyOriginatorFile)&quot; " />
```

Answer (score 5):

For VS2017 path was changed to:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX\bin\NETFX X.X.X Tools\`.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the SDK (.NET, or now the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

**Simply:**

In windows (according .net framework version **\B8.1A..** changes in the path), go to =>

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1
>   Tools

Write your **sn.exe** command:

```
sn -i D:\XX\MYProject.UI.api\MYProject.Gateway\my_certificate.pfx VS_KEY_AD6FD8AFB39B6C43
```

if it is password protected than it will want the pwd write it down

Answer (score 1):

Nope, looks like you need the SDK for that  :(

FYI, the Runtime itself would not be under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET` -- all it's files live [only] under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\vXXXXXX\`

Comment: No, that is the runtime folder. That contains some tools, but not sn.

Comment: @HenkHolterman (and OP) have edited the answer to make it clearer. I submit that a) there was an important point that the other answers didnt cover b) we should all remove our comments as they dont make sense with the answer as it is c) the downvoter should remove the downvote assuming there is agreement. As for how I'll remember to delete this... :)

Answer (score 1):

For VS2019 the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\sn.exe

still now i m unable to use VS command prompt. it showing me message like

** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.8.9
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>where sn.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).